# VSCode - format document or current line on Enter press

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to format current document or current line on `Enter` press? This is my setting in `VSCode`, `settings.json`:

`"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"`

so this setting does not have any effect:

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

and this setting does not helps to format on `Enter` press:

`"editor.formatOnType": true`

may be [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) (or any other extention) can trigger `editor.action.formatDocument` event on `Enter` press but I don't know how to do it.

Please help!

P.S. I tried this with [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros); In my `settings.json`:

```
"macros": {
    "formatOnEnter": [
      "cursorDown",
      "editor.action.formatDocument",
    ],
  }
```

and in my `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "macros.formatOnEnter",
},
```

document is formatted and cursor is jumping to new line but cursor does not creates new line.

And may be it is better to format only current line but how?

Comment: Personally, I can imagine few things more annoying than having my document reformat itself every time I pressed Enter.  What if you're editing a file written by someone else?  What if you have a few lines that make more sense when you violate the rules?

Comment: yes you are right. may be it is better to format current line on enter

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on `Editor: Format On Type`

[image]

You may check https://youtu.be/m-3Symq2-V8?t=53 to see how it works

Comment: it does not works when you have enabled: "files.autoSave": "afterDelay"

Comment: Try "ctrl+enter" binding from my answer it is not "enter", but very close

Answer (score 0):

By binding the Enter key to the format action, you're overriding its default behaviour (which is normally used for creating a new line). If you still want the Enter key to insert a new line after formatting the document and format the whole file, you'll need to chain commands, which is more complex and might require an extension like "multi-command". For big source files this kind of configuration can be CPU intensive too. Usually we write code and format it along the way with occasional help from IDE, but this way you want to always rely on some formatting rule forced on the project. You can also try to chain commands so that file is formatted on every save with similar approach which might be less CPU intensive if you safe file on demand.

If you decide to use "multi-command", here's a brief guide:

1. Install the extension: [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)
2. Update your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.formatThenNewline",
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.formatDocument",
            "editor.action.insertLineAfter"
        ]
    }
]
```

3. Update your keybindings.json to use the new multi-command:

```
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "multiCommand.formatThenNewline",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

As Enter key is overloaded and above solution might not work, you can instead just bind to a close shortcut like :

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "multiCommand.formatThenNewline",
    "when": "editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Comment: Does not work properly :( press Enter several times and you will see

Comment: It is not a normal way to use Enter key and this configuration indeed interfere with the natural behaviour of the Enter key.  Just use - Shift + Alt + F (on Windows/Linux) or Shift + Option + F (on Mac) or try to turn off files.autoSave and use editor.formatOnSave.

Comment: You can also bind the multi-command chain to the key on the keyboard that you never use and that solely doesn't have other command bind to it. For example: F12, some key on Numpad or Pause/Break key.